# the Asus A8N5X Motherboard Manual says maximum 4 GB memory is there a way to increase that?

Tags: memory, motherboard

The Asus A8N5X Motherboard Manual says maximum 4 GB DDR memory. 1 GB per slot. Is there a way to increase that? Such as perhaps by upgrading the CPU or am I just hopefully dreaming?

Comment: No; There is no way to increase that.  It is a limit of the design of the hardware itself.

Comment: Your only hope is that there _might_ be a firmware upgrade to support it, but it is a faint hope: it's most likely a hardware limitation. Without more memory, your best bet to improve performance is to use an SSD as a swap disc, but it needs to be one with a very high specification for maximum writes.

Comment: @AFH Firmware can only help so much.  In this case its multiple parts of the hardware itself are the reason for this limit.

Comment: @Ramhound - I fully accept that: I did say it was a slim chance. But without going into the hardware in great detail I could not eliminate it completely. I thought it worth checking before looking at more expensive options. Replacing a motherboard should not be taken lightly: apart from the board itself, a replacement with the same connectivity may well not support any of the existing memory and possibly not the current CPU either, not to mention the power supply's compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Your motherboard uses the nForce4 chipset which has a buildin memory controller limited to 4 GB (in 4x 1GB, 2x 2GB isn't going to work either).

So you are out of luck I'm afraid.

Besides: This is ancient hardware. Whatever upgrade you are going to throw at it, it won't make it much faster/better then it is now. And it is very questionable if any investment in this machine is going to be worth the money given its age.